# Vertical gallery in android

Tags: android, galleryview

i am developing an app, for which I need a gallery to be set in vertical mode instead of horizontal mode. my question is, is there any possibilities for me to show a vertical gallery kind of widget?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cant you use Listview instead?

Comment: If it can look like gallery I can use it. Do you have any working samples on it.

Comment: Have you got the solution? How can you send one item at a time to adapter.Can you please give me some example or explain it in brief?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you create a **custom adapter for the listview**? If you define a **custom adapter with one imageview** then it will be same as vertical Gallery view. So once you define this adapter then you will be having 1 imageview per one item so it will look like vertical gallery view.

FYI, here is a [listview with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012), you can use the same listview, play with it.

Comment: Glad that i had punched exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a ScrollView which contains some imageView setted to fill_parent , and then you can Scroll them as a vertical Gallery

Comment: Is it possible for me to add images to it dynamically to that scroll view?

Comment: you should use a `ListView`, as it will handle requesting the views for list items on demand. with a `ScrollView`, you have to figure out for yourself when to populate additional items.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. so i came to know that vertical gallery in android is not possible with the normal gallery widget. So I tried using Custom Listview with some modifications to change the look of the listview. Now my listview looks exactly like a vertical scrollable gallery.