# ScrollView of images with automated scrolling animation

Tags: android

How can i automate the scrolling behavior without having to press up/down keys on a Vertical SCrollview. I wanted a view that looks like a VERTICAL Gallery widget.

Expected UI:
1 Lauch activity
2 A vertical list of images is seen.
3 Navigates automatically throught the images in a ciruclar queue

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056760/vertical-gallery-in-android).

And just put one handler to call the listView position one by one for the Scrolling animation. If the Position comes at end then start from 0. With this way you will get what you want.

let me know if you have any query.